# Updating A Post Title Using GET Method and $wpdb Class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I have a programming exercise and I wanted to check if what I have done so far is the best way to update a post title based on setting the query string.  In my example below I create a link for updating the post and validate the origin with a nonce.  I used the template_redirect action as it only fires once where as the `wp` and `parse_query` actions seemed to fire multiple times.  The GET request can come from a form submit or link click but I've only attached the link example but the code should work for both situations.

```
function update_post_title() {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id = get_query_var( 'post_id', 0 );
    $post_title = get_query_var( 'post_title', '' );
    $post_nonce = get_query_var( 'update_post_title_nonce', '' );

    if( ! empty( $post_title ) AND $post_id > 0 ) {

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $post_nonce, 'update_post_title_action' ) ) {
            wp_die( 'Security check failed' );
        }

        $post_title = sanitize_text_field( $post_title );
        //$post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $post_title );
        $post_id = intval( $post_id );

        $rows_affected = $wpdb->update( 
                            $wpdb->posts, 
                            array( 'post_title' => $post_title ), 
                            array( 'ID' => $post_id ), 
                            array( '%s'), 
                            array( '%d' ) 
                        );
    }
}

function add_custom_query_vars( $public_query_vars ) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'post_id';
    $public_query_vars[] = 'post_title';
    $public_query_vars[] = 'update_post_title_nonce';

    return $public_query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_vars' );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'update_post_title' );
```

Sample link generate.

```
global $post;

<a href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( array( 
                                                'post_id' => 123, 
                                                'post_title' => 'The New Title', ), 
                                            site_url( $post->post_name ) ), 
                                            'update_post_title_action', 
                                            'update_post_title_nonce' ); 
    ?>">Click To Update</a>
```

Comment: I would just change intval() to a simple cast (int). It's faster and has less room for mess up, since it will always assume the input is in base 10. Instead, intval may switch to hex or octal depending on the form of the input, and this may be unwished.

Comment: The default base is 10 for intval().  The codec uses intval() in their sanitising  and escaping examples.  My main concern in my code is if I am using the correct action or not for processing the query string. https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: Yes, all looks right. You don't need query processing if you use wpdb methods, unless you use the query() method.

Comment: Ah ok so the $wpdb->update sanitises the data for me then?

Comment: Yes. Actually, you should be sure that no data is escaped at all. Quoting: "Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped). This means that if you are using GET or POST data you may need to use stripslashes() to avoid slashes ending up in the database." https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

Comment: I think that codec page is outdated because stripslashes() was only required when using older version of PHP that had magic quotes enabled on the server.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the server setup. I've personally never used it and always been fine without in the last couple years at least...